# sending a variable to an email from as3 to php

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm working on a flash content on my website that contains an input box and a submit button.
The user should put an answer of a question in the input box and when he clicks on submit, the answer should be sent to an email address.
The problem is, when a user enters an answer, I receive an empty email message.
Here are my codes:

**Text box's code:**

```
var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myData.answer = "";
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("MyDomain/..../example.php");
myRequest.data = myData;
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

**The button's code:**

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sen) ;
function sen(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL( new URLRequest("MyDomain/..../example.php"), "_self");
}
```

**and this is the PHP code:**

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST['answer']; 
$to = "MyMail@example.com";
$subject="Message from php";
mail($to,$subject,$text,"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

So what's wrong with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending data from as3 to a PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993631/sending-data-from-as3-to-a-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

You never defined the variable $text in your PHP code. You are probably missing in your code something like this:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

or you should use $answer variable instead of the $text variable.

You could write some debug code to see what you have submitted from your AS3 code:

```
<?php
$text = var_export($_POST, true);
// not used anyway
// $answer = $_POST['answer']; 
$to = "MyMail@example.com";
$subject="Message from php";
mail($to,$subject,$text,"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

This way you would get an email containing all the POST variables, so you can see which one you need to reference in your $_POST[] array.

Comment: I received this message:  array (
) so I guess the problem is in the as3 code, isn't it?

Comment: yup, i think you are missing loader.load() call. try reading this perhaps: http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_9/article_442-post-request-data-in-as3.htm

Comment: I did these instructions and I received an email contains: array (
  'answer' => '',
) and if I wrote something in the statment: variables.answer = "";  , ggg i.g, I recive this:array (
  'answer' => 'ggg',
)

Comment: then use `$text = $_POST['answer'];` in your php script and of course, assign some value to your `myData.answer = ...` in your AS3 code

Comment: Now I received an empty email again :\

Comment: I want the user to insert his answer, so I should leave     myData.answer = ""; empty. is that right? & sorry I'm new on prgramming.

Comment: You probably want to use something like: `myData.answer = myTextBox.text;`. You can find more info here: http://www.glyndavidson.co.uk/3D-CGI-Animation-Cinema-4D-Tutorials/Actionscript3DynamicTextBoxes.aspx

Comment: I don't know where is the problem, I keep on getting an empty email